# Nested looping and combinations

Tags: excel, nested, vba

I have this question:

Create a Sub with any combination of nested loops. This nested loop should take the baby girl names input (below) and print out every possible combination. These input names will need to appear in your workbook somewhere. Print out the combinations in the workbook itself.

Input
[image: names]

I have been able to get Penelope paired with all the middle names, but I can't figure out how to pair the rest of the first names. I don't know how to offset the active cell to the second first name and so on. this is what I have so far:

```
Sub part2()
    Dim combination As String
    Dim fName As String
    Dim mName As String

    Range("A1").Activate
    fName = ActiveCell.Value

    Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
        mName = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
        combination = fName & " " & mName
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3) = combination
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
    Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you need 2 nested loops for this. The first to loop through column A (first names) and for every row in column A loop through column B (middle names) and combine them:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub CombineNames()
    Dim wsNames As Worksheet
    Set wsNames = Worksheets("Sheet1") 'define which worksheet to use

    Dim lRow As Long
    lRow = wsNames.Cells(wsNames.Cells.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'find last used row

    Dim iRow As Long
    For iRow = 2 To lRow 'loop throug column A
        Dim jRow As Long
        For jRow = 2 To lRow 'for every row in column A loop through column B
            Debug.Print wsNames.Cells(iRow, "A").Value & " " & wsNames.Cells(jRow, "B").Value
              'change this line to your desired output
        Next jRow
    Next iRow
End Sub
```

**Note**
This assumes that column A and B have the same amount of rows. If that's not the case you will need to determine the last row for each column separately:

```
Dim lRowA As Long
lRowA = wsNames.Cells(wsNames.Cells.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'find last used row in column A
Dim lRowB As Long
lRowB = wsNames.Cells(wsNames.Cells.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row 'find last used row in column B
```

and adjust the loops to `For iRow = 2 To lRowA` and `For jRow = 2 To lRowB`.